# PlatformException(Error performing setData, PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions., null)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

**No error in my Dart Code, but I cannot write data to firestore,
i cannot write data to cloud firestore,
no error in my code: but error message comes again and again
Error is as Below::**

```
  W/Firestore( 9874): (21.3.0) [Firestore]: Write failed at user/6nattT06v0dfeeb6Rm9ablZuijU2/reports/reports_1: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
E/flutter ( 9874): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Error performing setData, PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions., null)
```

**Code Snippet:**

````
```

abstract class Database {
    Future createReport(Map<String, dynamic> reportData);
    }
    
    class FirestoreDatabase implements Database{
    FirestoreDatabase({@required this.uid}) : assert (uid!=null);
    final String uid;
    
    //TODO: to create a report hard coded:
    Future createReport(Map<String, dynamic> reportData) async {
    final path = 'user/$uid/reports/reports_1';
    final documentReference = Firestore.instance.document(path);
    await documentReference.setData(reportData);
    }
    }
    void _createReport(BuildContext context) { final database = Provider.of<Database>(context); database.createReport({ 'crime Type' : 'Blogging', 'Description' : 'description needs to be provided', }); }```
    
    ```class Report{
    Report({@required this.crimeType, @required this.description});
    final String crimeType;
    final String description;
    //TODO: to map data to Firestore
    Map<String, dynamic> toMap(){
    return{
    'CrimeType' : crimeType,
    'Description': description,
    };
    }
    }```
````

**Firebase Rules:**

```
rules_version = '2'; 
service cloud.firestore {
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
 match /users/{uid}/Reports/{document=**} {
 allow read, write; }}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED!!!:

OLD:

Try changing your Firestore rule to:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{uid}/Reports/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

The only thing that was really changed here is this line:

```
allow read, write: if true;
```

If that does not work, try:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

NEW:

My first answer was actually insecure, because using the

```
if true
```

allowed anyone with access to your firebase project to have admin rights. Rather use this instead, which only works if the request from the app is authenticated:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Sorry for the late edit, have a great time coding everyone!

Comment: Mark it as an answer for the others to see then :)